# MongoDB Error: Cannot create property '_id' on string

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, insert

I'm using Node.js and Express on Heroku, with the MongoDB addon.
My database connection works fine and I can successfully push some data in, but not other.

Here is the database connection:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(mongoURI, function (err, database) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
}

// Save database object from the callback for reuse.
db = database;
console.log("Database connection ready");

// Initialize the app.
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || dbport, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
});
});
```

I can successfully push my Twitter API response into the database like this:

```
db.collection(TWEETS_COLLECTION).insert(data);
```

('data' is just a JSON variable)

But when I try to push another JSON variable into the database in the same method, I get an error. Code:

```
var jsonHash = '{"hashtag":"","popularity":1}';
var objHash = JSON.parse(jsonHash);
objHash.hashtag = req.body.hashtag;
JSON.stringify(objHash);
collection(HASHTAG_COLLECTION).insert(jsonHash);
```

And the error:

> TypeError: Cannot create property '_id' on string '{"hashtag":"myhash","popularity":1}'
>   at Collection.insertMany...
>   ...

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you are getting the `jsonHash` variable from but I think you are doing unecessary JSON-handling here. You are also inserting the wrong variable, you want to insert `objHash` which is a valid object to insert, now you are inserting `jsonHash` which is just a string. `JSON.stringify(objHash);` is not doing anything as you are not saving the JSON returned from the function. I think you want something like this?

```
var objHash = {
      hashtag: "",
      popularity:1
};
objHash.hashtag = req.body.hashtag;
collection(HASHTAG_COLLECTION).insert(objHash);
```

Comment: Thankyou! This worked. I guess I didn't need any of that JSON handling.

Answer (score 0):

`jsonHash` is still a string. May be you want to save `objHash` instead without `JSON.stringify` ?